# Android how to share webview cookies for third part libs

Tags: android, redirect, cookies, webview

I try to download html source of some url. For this I use Ion library (https://github.com/koush/ion). The problem is that it always redirect me to login page (and Ion lib download source of this login page). I want to log in through webview and than share cookies session to Ion library. Then I would be able download html source of url without redirecting. Is there any way how to do this.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

this will give you the cookies:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
//do what you need with cookies
}
```

and this how to set cookies:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(url, cookies);
```

Comment: Thanks, i can get cookies by this way. My problem is that I cannot set this cookies to my lib. So lib still redirect me. Is there any way how to set this cookies from webview to entire app?

Comment: you can try this:
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(url, cookies); // String cookies